# LINQ Select to entity reference's reference?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, select

I have a three entity hierarchy for telecommunications exchanges in an SQL Express database and I'm using the Entity Framework to run some LINQ queries on it.

`Exchange` is in a `SubRegion` which is in a `Region`. Obviously I also have an implicit `Exchanges` in `Region` relationship as well.

```
(Exchange) *...1 (SubRegion) *...1 (Region)
           *.....................1
```

Sometimes the user wants to see all the exchanges in a region or in a sub-region. When I use the following LINQ query, I get an exception.

```
Data.Region region = regionComboBox.SelectedItem as Data.Region;

var esas = from esa in JITScheduleContainer.Exchanges
    where esa.SubRegion.Region == region
    select esa;

exchangeComboBox.Items.AddRange(esas.ToArray());
```

Exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of
>   type 'CpasJitScheduler.Data.Region'.
>   Only primitive types ('such as Int32,
>   String, and Guid') are supported in
>   this context.

Is there anything in the EF model I need to do or some other way of reference a parent's parent object?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that I could use the `int Id` field to compare. Resulting LINQ statement:

```
Data.Region region = regionComboBox.SelectedItem as Data.Region;

var esas = from esa in Container.Exchanges
           where esa.SubRegion.Region.Id == region.Id
           select esa;

exchangeComboBox.Items.AddRange(esas.ToArray());
```